# How to solve for the inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

How would one solve the following inverse Laplace transform?

$$\mathscr{L}_s^{-1}\left\{\frac{2s}{\left(s-1\right)^2+7}\right\}$$

I know from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20laplace%20transform%20%282s%29%2F%28%28s-1%29%5E2%2B7%29) that the answer is:

$$\frac{2 e^t \left[\sin(\sqrt{7} t)+\sqrt{7} \cos(\sqrt{7} t)\right]}{\sqrt{7}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform is equal to $$\frac{2}{(s-1)^2+\sqrt{7}^2}+\frac{2(s-1)}{(s-1)^2+\sqrt{7}^2}$$ which turn into cosine and sine transforms combined with the first shift theorem.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (and couldn't see). Thank you for pointing out the first shift theorem as well, I wouldn't have thought of using that. Is there a trick to finding these "hidden" sums of transforms?